# Congratulations! Matter Modeling rocked at Winter Bash 2021!

Tags: discussion, participation, winter-bash, congratulations, stackexchange

#### Winter Bash 2021 is now over and I want to thank everyone who participated!

I think it was very successful, and in many ways [even more fun than last year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374831/391772).

Furthermore, one of our very own diamond moderators was the first (network-wide!) to get one of the hats:

[image]

And this also happened to be the hardest hat to get, having been awarded to only 5 users (including Tyberius) network-wide out of 757,923 users that got hats:

[image]

Also, out of 757,923 users that got hats, one of our users ([uhoh](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/users/201/uhoh)) ***came in 13th*** place overall for most hats awarded,   and one of us ***came in 7th***:

[image]

The 2021 Winter Bash was much more difficult to collect hats compared to last year's one, and many hats were not possible for Matter Modelers to obtain here (for example, there was a hat granted to people for having 5 reopen reviews validated by other users, but we didn't even have 5 reopen votes to review in the first place). In light of that, I'm especially proud to say that we earned 199 hats, which was more than a lot of sites far bigger than us!

[image]

Finally, ***thank you*** to everyone that participated, especially the following users who earned 4 or more hats on MMSE (I stopped at 4 because there's so many users with 3 hats that it bleeds into the next webpage in that list):

[image]

Finally, [here's a related blogpost on The Overflow Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/01/06/the-bash-is-over-but-the-season-lives-a-little-longer/?cb=1).

#### Thanks again everyone, see you next year!

Comment: I was 13th? Except for having fun wearing them upside down I still haven't figured out what they are/how they work. I recently found out [I'm 2nd](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/374530/303080) in total network questions but at least I'm making progress towards understanding what questions are for :-)